# Missing Maven Dependency on Locally installed atrifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a .jar file, which I want to use in my current project which I am building with Maven. After some research I figured out that I need to install it locally. This I did using:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="D:\Eclipse Workspace\TextOnlyJam\adapterLib\lwjgladapter.jar" -DgroupId=lwjgladapter -DartifactId=lwjgladapter -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar`
```

I then added the dependency into my pom like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>lwjgladapter</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgladapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My project in exclipse now manages to resolve all dependencies and does not give me any compile errors. However after cleaning and updating my maven project several times, I still get the following error when running an install:

```
Failure to find lwjgladapter:lwjgladapter:jar:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

I assume that maven is looking for the artifact in the wrong location, however I can not figure out what I need to change here.

(I am also not sure if I need to add the dependency into , since it does not seem to change anything when I do.)

Comment: Where does the jar coming from?

Comment: That should be sufficient; you should (a) inspect your local maven directory to make sure it's there, and (b) make sure your IDE is using the same local cache.

Comment: I built the jar myself locally, how do I ensure the cache is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just figured out that it was just a stupid mistake on my end. I looked into the repository folder and found, that my jar file was named `.jar``

So yeah, a simple copy and past error. Thanks for the help so far!